# Who is greater Vishnu, Ram or Krishna?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, rama

Who is greater **Vishnu**, **Ram** or **Krishna**?

Comment: Different names of the same person. Called Vishnu because he pervaded the universe when he came to beg for three paces of land from Bali. Called Rama because Ramante yasmin prajah sa Ramah- the one in whom praja or the jivas enjoy due to Brahmananda is Rama. Krishna because he attracts people towards him. Akarshanat Krishnah due to his beautiful form.

Comment: Are they different? (If we ignore sectarian views for a moment)

Comment: Depends on which sampradaya you subscribe to....(eg:Gaudiya Vaishanavas claim Lord Shree Krishna is the Supreme Brahman while Ramanandi Vaishanavas claim its Prabhu Shree Ram)

Comment: They both are Vishnu representing different attributes and withdifferent goals but one difference if we take only Valmiki Ramayan and Vyas Mahabhat is that Sri Krishna was aware of his divine hood unlike Sri Ram.

Answer (score 5):

**सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।**

Both Śrī Hari Nāräyan and Śrī Krishnā are the incarnation of the Perfect Supreme Personality of the GodHead Śrī Rāma.

Their is no difference between Avatār and Avatāri as **पूर्णमद: पूर्णमिदं पूर्णात्** concept always apply. Like wise their is no difference between Śrī Rāma himself and his incarnations like Śrī Hari Narayan, Śrī Krishnā etc.
[image]

To thīnk bigger and smāller is just a mere satisfaction of one's false Ëgo and nothing else.

That's Śrī Rāma who incarnates himself as Vīshnu;

> ततस्त्वमसि दुर्धर्षात्तस्माद् भावात् सनातनात् ।
>
> रक्षार्थं सर्वभूतानां विष्णुत्वं उपजग्मिवान् ॥

(**Śrī Vālmiki Rāmāyaṇa 7.104.9)**

"After my prayers in the begining of the creation, Oh Rāma ! You forsaken Your durdharsa (the swarupa which is difficult to be achieved for many) i.e. eternal Bhava (the eternal two armed Śrī Rāma form) and assumed the form of Vīshnu for the sake of protection and sustenance of all the beings."

One thing I want to say here is that Śrī Rāmayana is an incarnation of Vedās so it has the same Authority as Vedās, it means whatever has been written in Rāmayana is final;

As said;

> वेदवेद्ये परेपुंसि जाते दशरथात्मजे ।
>
> वेदःप्राचेतसादासीत् साक्षाद् रामायणात्मना ॥
>
> तस्माद्रामायणं देवि "वेद एव न संशयः॥

**(Śrīmad Valmiki Ramayan and Agastya Samhita)**

The one who is the son of Dasarātha is the Vedvedyā i.e. the supreme personality known from the Vedās, on his appearance the Vedas themselves incarnated in the form of Śrī Rāmayana from the mouth of Prāchetas Vālmiki Muni. Lord Shiva himself says, O Goddess! There is no doubt that Śrī Rāmayana is the Veda itself.

Śrīmad Valmiki Ramayana is Veda itself as said in Vālmiki Rāmayan;

"**वेदोपबृंहणार्याय" तावग्राहयत प्रभुः ॥**

In Skandh Puran also;

'**रामायणाद काव्यं सर्व "वेदार्थ सम्मतम्"**॥"

(Skāndh Puranā uttarkhand)

In Mantra Ramayana aslo;

"**वेदार्थानभिज्ञे सति न रामायणमपराद्धघति**"

So Ramayana's authority (Śrīmad Vālmiki Rāmayan & Śrīmad Rāmcharit Mānas, as Tuslidās ji maharāj is incarnation of Śrī Vālmiki muni as mentioned in scriptures) is same is of Vedas.
[image]

Now, Back to point,

It's Śrī Rāma himself from whom Brahmā, Vīshnu, Maheshā gets incarnated.

> उपजहिं जासु अंस ते नाना। संभु विरंचि विष्णु भगवाना।।

**(Śrīmad Ramcharit Manas, Balkand)**

Meaning :- Many Lord Shivā, Brahmā and Vīshnu appear from the mere part of Śrī Rāma.

**Same is mentioned in Skāndh Puranā uttarkhand in Narad Sanathkumar Dialogue;**

> ब्रह्मविष्णु महेशाद्या यस्यांशा लोकसाधकाः ।
>
> नमामि देवं चिद्रूपं विशुद्धं परमं भजे ॥

Meaning:~ I bow down to the most pure Sachidānand Śrī Rāma, who fulfills the desired wishes of the whole world, the deities like Brahmā, Vīshnu and Maheshā etc. are only his mere parts. I concentrate my mind on his hymns.

Same in **Bhārdwaj Samhitā;**

> नारायणोपि रामशः शंखचक्रगदाव्जधृक्। चतुर्भुजस्वरूपेण वैकुण्ठे च
> प्रकाशते॥ अवतारा बहवः सति कलाश्र्चांशविभूतयः। राम एव परं ब्रह्म
> सच्चिदानन्दमव्ययम्।।

*(Śrī Bhardwaj Samhita)*

Śrī Hāri Nāräyana is an incarnation of Śrī Rāma and shines in Vāikunth in the form of four arms with conch, chakra and mace. There are many incarnations of Śrī Rāma differentiating by Kalãs, Part, Vibhuti etc. But Śrī Rāma himself is Par-Brahma who is devoid of Māya in his two armed form (human form).

**As Śrī Rāma himself says;**

> योऽपि नारायणोऽनन्तो लोकानां प्रभवाव्ययः । ममैव परमा मूर्तिः करोति
> परिपालनम्॥

(**श्रीमद्रामायणे वाल्मीकीये अद्भुतोत्तरकाण्डे भगवद्धनूमत्संवादो नाम चतुर्दशः सर्गः)**

The Lord of the infinite worlds, who is inseparable Nāräyan, is my supreme form and maintains the universe.

As said in Śrīmad Kurmā Puranā;

> मत्स्यः कूर्मो वराहो नरहरिरतुलो वामनो जामदग्निः सभ्राता कंसशत्रुः
> करुणमदवपुर्लक्षिविध्वंसनश्च । एते चान्येऽपि सर्वे तरणिकुलभुवो यस्य
> जाताः कुलांशे तं व्याप्तं ब्रह्मतेजं विमलगुणमयं रामचन्द्रं नमामि ॥

(Śrīmad Kurmā Puranā)

Matsyā, Kurmā, Varahā, the incomparably brilliant Śrī Naräsimha and Vāmana, Yamadagni Parãshurāma, Lord Śrī Krishnā, the enemy of Kansha with his brother Baldevā, the compassionate body Buddha, the destroyer of Mleksha, Śrī Kālki, these ten incarnations and others who are counted in incarnation. Prithu, Rishbhā etc, all these are born in the solar family, are born from the Amshā of Purushā, I bow down to that same Purushā Maharāj Śrī Rāmachandrā who is omnipresent and sacchidānandā.
[image]

*Even Ved Narāyana is saying same thing;*

> ब्रह्मादिपञ्चब्रह्माणो यत्र विश्रान्तिमाप्नुयुः । तदखण्डसुखाकारं
> रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥

(**Yajurvedā Shrüti Pānch Brahmõpanishād**)

I worship the lotus feet of Lord Śrī Rāmachandrā, the cause of eternal bliss, where the five Brahmas (Shri Shiva, Shri Hāri Vīshnu, Shri Ganesha, Bhagwati Durga and Shri Surya) along with Brahma etc. always find rest (ashraya).

> एतेषु चैव सर्वेषु तत्त्वं च ब्रह्म तारकम् । राम एव परं ब्रह्म राम एव
> परं तपः ।। राम एव परं तत्त्वं श्रीरामो ब्रह्म तारकम् ।।
> वायुत्रेणोक्तास्ते योगीन्द्रा ऋषयो विष्णुभक्ता हनूमन्तं पप्रच्छुः
> रामस्याङ्गानि नो ब्रूहीति । वायुपुत्रं विघ्नेशं वाणीं दुर्गां
> क्षेत्रपालकं सूर्यं चन्द्रं नारायणं नारसिंहं वायुदेवं वाराहं
> तत्सर्वान्त्समात्रान्त्सीतं लक्ष्मणं शत्रुघ्नं भरतं विभीषणं
> सुग्रीवमङ्गदं जाम्बवन्तं प्रणवमेतानि रामस्याङ्गानि जानीथाः ।

(**Yajurvedā Shrüti RāmRahāshyopanishād)**

In all the scriptures like Vedās, the supreme principle is 'Tāraka Rāma' in the form of Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is the Supreme Brāhman. Śrī Rāma is the supreme form. Śrī Rāma is the Supreme Being. Śrī Rāma is Tarakabrahma. Hanumān Ji preached to the devotee of Śrī Hāri Vīshnu and other Rishis "I myself, Śrī Ganēshā, Goddess Saraswati, Goddess Durgā, All the Guardian (Khetra Pāl), Sun (Suryā), Moon, Lord Śrī Hāri Nāräyana, Lord Naräsimha, Lord Vāsudev (Śrī Krishnā), Lord Vāraha etc. all are the mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma. Lakshmāna, Shātrughna, Bharata, Vibhishana, Sugriva, Angad, Jambavant and Pranav (Om ॐ) are also mere parts of Lord Śrī Rāma.

> यो रामः कृष्णतामेत्य सार्वात्म्यं प्राप्य लीलया । अतोषयद्देव्मौनिपटलं
> तं नतोऽस्म्यहम्।।

(**Atharvaveda Shruti Krishnopanishad**)

That Śrī Rāma, who transformed himself (incarnated) as Krishnā, attained Sarvaatmakta (सार्वभौमिकता) by his very lilā (divine exploits, pastimes); and thus deities-sages-masses were completely satisfied on this earth. I make prostration before that same Śrī Rāma.

> वासुदेवादि मुर्तिनाम् चतुर्नाम् कारणं परम्। चतुर्विंशति मुर्तिनाम्
> आश्रय श्रीरामः शरणं मम।।

(**Brihād Brahmā Samhitā 2.7.8, Śrī Hāri Nāräyana to Brahmā)**

The supreme cause of the four vyuhas, such as Vāsudeva. Śrī Rāma, the shelter of the twenty-four avtars, is my refuge.

One thing has become clear from here that the same Supreme Soul who is called Śrī Rāma is established in all forms as said in Vedāvatāar Śrīmad Valmiki Rāmayana,

> एतत्तदुक्तमव्यक्तमक्षरं ब्रह्म सम्मितम् । देवानां हृदयं सौम्य गुह्यं
> रामः परंतपः ॥

(**Śrīmad Valmiki Rāmayana 7.119.32**)

Śrī Rāma is the eternal akshar brahman mentioned in Vedās who is the innerself (heart) of all Gods.

> रामाद् विशिष्टः कोऽन्योऽस्ति कश्चित् सौमित्रिणा समः

(**Śrīmad Valmiki Ramayana 5.39.53**)

"Who else is greater than Śrī Rāmā? and who else is equal to even Lakshmana? (means no one is greater than him)

> रामात् नास्ति परोदेवो रामात् नास्ति परंव्रतम्

(**Padmā Puranā, Pātālkhand 34/41A**)

No God is superior than Śrī Rāma; No penance has greater fruit than Śrī Rāma.

Only Lord Śrī Rāma is pervaded in all forms, that's why no one can be small or big. If you are down grading any form of Śrī Rāma, it means that you are down grading Śrī Rāma through them which will not be tolerated at all. The one with eight arms lord is also ours, the one with four arms lord is also ours, the one with two arms is also ours, the Jagannāth with half arms is also ours and the one without arms i.e. Shaligrām is also ours.

One thing to note here is that the Supreme Sōul who pervades is the two armed has been called the root of all. Let's understand through Proofs;

> द्विहस्तमेवऋञ्च शुद्धस्फटिकसन्निभम्। मरीचिमण्डले संस्थं
> बाणाद्यायुधलाञ्छितम्।। किरीट हार केयूर वनमाला विराजितम् । पीताम्बर धरं
> सौम्यं रूपमाद्यमिदं हरेः॥

(**Narad Panchratra Śrī Padma Samhita)**

Concluding meaning is that, In the Sun (the divine light/effulgence), there is the original primeval-form of Śrī Hāri having one face and two hands with bow and arrow."

Same is their in **Narada Pānchratra Ānand Samhitā and Sundāri Tãntra;**

> आनन्दो द्विधः प्रोक्तो मूर्तश्चामूर्त एव च । अमूर्तस्याश्रयोमूर्तः
> परमात्मा नराकृतिः ।। स्थूलं चाष्टभुजं प्रोक्तं सूक्ष्मं प्रोक्तं
> चर्तुर्भुजम् । द्विभुजं परात्परं प्रोक्तं तस्मादेतत्त्रयं यजेत् ॥
> सर्वशक्तिकलानाथं द्विभुजं रघुनन्दनम् ।
> द्विभुजाद्राघवान्नित्यात्सर्वमेतत्प्रवर्तते ।।

Infact,

Wherever in the Vedās there has been a discussion of Parambrahma Paramatma, the word Dwibhuja (Two Armed) has been used for them.

> सं "बाहुभ्यां" धमति सं पतत्रैर्द्यावाभूमी जनयन्देव एकः॥

(**Rig ved 10.81.3)**

Here the word Bhāubhyam (बाहुभ्यां) has been used in Dwi-Vachan (द्विवचन) representing two armes.

Even in **Purushā Suktā of Vedās** the sanskrit word used for arms has been used in Dwi-Vachan representing two arms of supreme Lord Śrī Rāma, (10 & 11th mantra)

> ब्राह्मणोऽस्य मुखमासीद् "**बाहू राजन्य:** कृत:"। •
>
> यत्पुरुषं व्यदधुः कतिधा व्यकल्पयन् मुखं किमस्यासीत् "**किं बाहू"** किमूरू
> पादाऽउच्येते।।

So the **Purush Sukta is exclusively dedicated to Śrī Rāma** but as Śrī Hari Narayan and Śrī Krishnā are his incarnations so this applies to them as well as their is no difference between Avatār and Avatāri.

Same like many Shlokā are in Vedās which clearly speak up the same thing.

> यो विश्वचर्षणिरुत विश्वतोमुखो यो विश्वतस्पाणिरुत विश्वतस्पृथः। सं
> **"बाहुभ्यां"** भरति सं पतत्त्रैर्द्यावापृथिवी

(**Atharvaveda 13.2.23**)

> विश्वतश्चक्षु विश्वतोमुखोविश्वबाहुरु विश्वतस्पात्। **"सं बाहुभ्यां"** धमति
> संपतत्रै र्द्यावाभूमीजनयन्देव एकः ॥

(**Krishnā Yajurvedā Shvetashvatara Upanishad 3.3)**

> वि॒श्वतः॑ऽपा॒दिति॑ वि॒श्वतः॑ऽपात्। सम्। "**बा॒हुभ्या॒मति॑ बा॒हुभ्या॑म्**"।
> धम॑ति। सम्। पत॑त्रैः।

(**Shukla Yajurveda 17.19**)

So from here it has been clear that the two armed form of God his Original Source of everything,

As Tulsidas Maharaj has written in Ramcharit Manas,

> पुरुष प्रसिद्ध प्रकास निधि प्रगट परावर नाथ ।
>
> रघुकुलमनि मम स्वामि सोइ कहि सिवँ नायउ माथ॥

That **Purushā who is famous in the Vedās and Puranās,** the supreme being, who is manifested in all forms is the lord of all beings, Maya and the world, that Rāghukul Mani Śrī Rāma is my master - saying this, Shivā bowed to him.

That's why he has written;

> जगत प्रकास्य प्रकासक रामू। मायाधीस ग्यान गुन धामू।।

In short, the whole universe (including Devi, Devata and Panch Brahma) are illuminated by the only one illuminator i.e. Śrī Rāma.

As **Śrī Parashara Smriti** clearly says;

> राम एव परं ब्रह्म परमात्माभिधीयते।
>
> रामात्परतरं नास्ति यत्किचित्स्थूलसूक्ष्मकम्॥
>
> ब्रह्मविष्णुशिवाः सर्वेइंद्रो निर्वरुणो यमः ।
>
> सूर्यश्चंद्रश्च खं भूमिराकाशस्त्वनिलो ह्यपः॥
>
> सर्वे ते रामचंद्रस्य तेजसा संप्रतिष्ठिताः ।
>
> भूतं भव्यं भविष्यच्च सर्वे रामसमुद्भवम्॥

Meaning- Lord Śrī Rāmbhadrā is the Supreme God, whatever is gross and subtle, none of them is beyond Śrī Rāma, that is why Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva all these and Indra, Agni, Varun, Yama, Sun, Moon, Heaven, Earth, sky, wind, water, all these have been established by the glory of Lord Śrī Rāmachandrā and all these three times past, future and present and whatever will be born and has been born in these three times, all that has been born from Śrī Rāma only.

So from here we can conclude that Śrī Rāma is alone Par Brahma who resides in the heart of all Gods.

As Tulsidas Maharaj has cleared in Śrīmad Rāmcharit Manas that;

> प्राननाथु रघुनाथ गोसाईं। जो बड़ होत सो राम बड़ाईं॥

Who so ever is big is bigger by the praise of Śrī Rāma.

As Valmiki Rāmayana says;

> रामाद् विशिष्टः कोऽन्योऽस्ति कश्चित् सौमित्रिणा समः

(**Śrī Valmiki Rāmayana 5.39.53**)

"Who else is greater than Śrī Rāmā? and who else is equal to even Lakshmana?
[Means Śrī Rāmā is free from anyone equal to or greater than him, and there is none equal to even Lakshmana.]"

Same is their in Śrīmad Bhagwat mahapurana;

> नेदं यशो रघुपतेः सुरयाच्ञयाऽऽत्त लीलातनोरधिकसाम्यविमुक्तधाम्नः।
> रक्षोवध जलधिबन्धनमस्त्रपूगैः किं तस्य शत्रुहनने कपयः सहायाः।।

(**Śrīmad Bhagwat Mahapurana 9.11.20**)

Parikshit! There is no one like Lord Śrī Raghūvara, then how can anyone be greater than him? He had done this Leela (past times) only by the prayers of the gods. In such a situation, it is not a matter of great pride for Raghuvansh-Shiromani that he killed the demons with weapons or built a bridge over the sea. Well, did they need the help of monkeys to kill the enemies? All this is His Leela.
[image]

One thing should always be noted that anything which applies to Śrī Rāma will be applied to his incarnations too as their is no difference between Avatar and Avatari.

Please forgive this servent for Grammatical mistakes as my mother tongue is Hindi I face problem in writing my answers in English by some hook and crook this servent has translated the whole Article.

Hail to Perfect Supreme Personality Of Godhead Śrī SitāRāmā.❤️

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya

Comment: Beautiful and extremely well researched Answer Shiv Ji! Please accept my humble pranaam!

Comment: Excellent! Upvoted+1 For your efforts and diverse sources 

Comment: Some more verses that praise Prabhu Shree Ramachandra: मयैव पूर्यते विश्वं मयैव प्रलयं ब्रजेत् । अहंहि भगवानीशः स्वयंज्योतिः सनातनः । ४७ ।। परमात्मा परंब्रह्म मत्तो ह्यन्यन्न विद्यते । इत्येतत्परमं ज्ञानं भवेत कथितं मया ॥४८॥ (~ śrī Rāma Gītā) & कृष्णोंऽशांशो ह एवास्य वृन्दावनविभूषणः ॥ एते चांशकलाश्चैव रामस्तु भगवान् स्वयम् । ब्रह्मा विष्णुश्च रुद्रश्च महेन्द्रः श्रीस्तथैव च ॥ (Adi-Ramayana 1.9.17-18)

Comment: Rāmastūbhagvāna swyam !!!  __/| |\__

Comment: I like the Purnamadah Purnamidam part 

Answer (score 2):

**द्विभुजाद् राघवै नित्यं सर्वमतेत्प्रवर्तते।
परान् नारायणोश्चैव कृष्ण परतराद् अपि।
उभयपरात्मनः श्रीमानः रामो दशरथि स्वराट्‌‌।।**
~ Anand samhita

**परान् नारायणोश्चैव कृष्ण परतराद् अपि।
यो वै परतमः श्रीमान् रामो दशरथि स्वराट्‌‌।।**
~Vashisht samhita

meaning of both shlokas:-
Beyond Narayana and krishna and beyond that, Shri dasrath putra Ramchandra is supreme personality of godhead.

and again in bhusundi ramayan also known as aadi ramayan

**मत्स्यं कुर्मं वराहं नृहरिथ हरिं वामनं हंसरुप यज्ञं नारायणाख्यं भार्गवं वै हयास्यम्।
प्रद्युम्नं वासुदेवं कलिमलदमनं रेवतीप्राणनाथं बुद्धं कल्कि यद्
अन्त्ये न भवति सकलं ब्रह्म रामं स्मरामि।।**

(श्रीमदादि रामायण)

I remember Rama the whole (परिपुर्ण) brahman who took avtar matsya, kurma, varah , Nrihari( narsimha),  Hari, Vamana, the swan, sacrifice, Narayana, the Bhrigu( parshuramji), the horse-faced (hayagriva), Pradyumna, Vasudeva, the suppressor of the impurities of Kali, the lord of the life of Revati (balram), the Buddha, Kalki,

In Maha ramayan (not yoga vasisht)

**रामान् नास्ति परो ध्ययो इति जगतां प्रभुः।**

There is only one supreme god ie bhagwan shri Ramchandra.

**यथा लोकेषु गोलोकः सरयु निम्नगासु च।
शक्तीनां च यथा सीता रामो भगवतामपि।।**

(Maha ramayan)

Among all lokas , golok is best as it contains saket lok in centre and among all rivers, saryu is best , among all powers, maa Sita is best and among all bhagwan ( narsimha, narayan, krishna etc) shri Ram is the best.

**दशावतारव्येऽपि रामकृष्णौ महत्तमौ।
ताभ्यामपि वरः पुर्वः सत्यसंधो रघुत्तमः।।**

Anand Ramayan Manohar 3.29b &30a

Among all ten avtars , Ram and Krishna are important and among these two, Shri Ram is best.

Answer (score 1):

The question is based on the premise that Vishnu, Rama and Krishna are separate from each other. This premise has repeatedly been struck down by scriptures. The same personality known as Narayana/ Vishnu comes on earth for the benefit of the sadhus in different forms which bewilder one to think that they’re separate from him.

This has been explained in the Bhagavatam and other texts, wherein just as an actor being the same person takes on different guises, so also Bhagavan being the same, takes on different forms. He appears different owing to his Maya or illusion. Let’s see what the scriptures say:

> The Lord appeared in His original form, with ornaments and weapons in His hands. Although this ever-existing form is not visible in the material world, He nonetheless appeared in this form. Then, in the presence of His father and mother, **He assumed the form of Vāmana, a brāhmaṇa-dwarf, a brahmacārī, just like a theatrical actor**. 
> -*Śrimad Bhagavatam [8.18.12](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/18/12/)*
>
> नट इव कपट चरित कर नाना। सदा स्वतंत्र एक भगवाना॥ - He performs many delusional activities like an actor, but actually **he is only one independent God**. 
> -*Ramacharitmanas Lanka Kanda 73.6*

Accordingly, the scriptures are very clear that Bhagavan himself appears from the womb of Kausalya and Devaki taking on the names, Rama and Krishna respectively. And as stated above, he appears to be of human form only because of Maya. Let’s analyse.

#### Rama

The Ayodhyakanda of the Srimad Ramayana describes the birth of Vishnu himself as follows:

> स हि देवैरुदीर्णस्य रावणस्य वधार्थिभिः।
> अर्थितो मानुषे लोके **जज्ञे विष्णुः सनातनः**॥
>
> **That Rama - was the eternal Vishnu** who was born on earth as prayed by celestials to kill the egoistic Ravana
> -*Valmiki Ramayana [2.1.7](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga1/ayodhyasans1.htm#Verse7)*

Further, Tulasidasji describes Rama as Mayamanushya Hari, i.e. Vishnu (Hari) who appears as human due to his Maya:

> रामाख्यं जगदीश्वरं सुरगुरुं **मायामनुष्यं हरिं**। वन्देऽहं… - I bow to the lord of the worlds and guru of the devatas (or best among the devatas) **known as Rama, who is Hari appearing as a human due to illusion**. 
> - *Ramacharitmanas Sundarakanda Managalacharana Shloka 1, third line.*

#### Krsna

The Srimad Bhagavatam describes the birth of Vishnu from the womb of Devaki. He appears as a small baby holding his ayudhas and when requested by Devaki, transforms himself into a prakrita shishu, just like an actor does.

> देवक्यां देवरूपिण्यां **विष्णु: सर्वगुहाशय:**।
> आविरासीद् यथा प्राच्यां दिशीन्दुरिव पुष्कल:॥
>
> Then the Supreme Personality of Godhead, **Viṣṇu, who is situated in the core of everyone’s heart, appeared from the heart of Devakī** in the dense darkness of night, like the full moon rising on the eastern horizon.
>  -*Srimad Bhagavatam [10.3.8](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/3/7-8/)*

Just as the Ramacharitmanas calls Rama as Mayamanushya Hari, so also the Bhagavatam calls Krishna as Mayamanushya, again meaning the lord who appears like a human due to his Maya:

> वीर्याणि…**मायामनुष्यस्य** वदस्व विद्वन्॥७॥ - Oh learned sage, kingly describe the activities of the **Lord who appears like a human due to Maya** 
> -*Srimad Bhagavatam [10.1.7](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/1/5-7/)*

Therefore from the above it is abundantly clear that the same lord takes on different appearances, just as an actor puts different costumes. And thus the question of which form is superior doesn’t hold good. It’s like asking is an actor dressed like a snowman superior or when he is dressed like a joker? Doesn’t matter it’s the same guy who eats the same food and will  consequently have the same strength irrespective of his appearance.